# Check if AzureAD guest users still exists in their home tenant

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2b

We are have several customer teams and a lot of B2B guest users in our AzureAD.
Recently noticed that when a user is deleted in the home tenant, it will still remain in our AD.

Other than deleting it after a period of inactivity, is it possible, to do a regular cleanup like (pseudocode)

```
For each user in guest users
   if removed from home tenant
      delete user
```

To do this, I assume there must be some kind of flag in the guest user in our tenant. Would be nice to do it in Graph or PowerShell. Any clever ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can manage guest access with [access reviews](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/governance/manage-guest-access-with-access-reviews).

The idea behind the access review is that guest users participate in the review and re-certify their access.

When an access review is finished, you can then make changes and remove access for guests who no longer need it.

The Graph API supports [access review](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/accessreviewsv2-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) but I would recommend to start with the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/clean-up-stale-guest-accounts) and ask later if you need a help with some part of the access review flow.

Comment: Access review requires additional license and cannot review guest users that are not member of a group. Many users only have (had) only access to a specific sharepoint location.